# c#: Speech to text using any api

Tags: c#, .net, google-translate, google-translator-toolkit

How to detect language and convert speech to text? Is Google APi support it? If yes then can anyone put any example of code?

Please help needed to convert speech to text?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you use C# 3.5 and higher u can Add a reference to the `System.Speech` namespace using the `Add Reference` in the Solution Explorer.

Then take a look at this Articles:

[Speech recognition, speech to text, text to speech, and speech synthesis in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/483347/Speech-recognition-speech-to-text-text-to-speech-a)

[C# Speech to Text](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/380027/Csharp-Speech-to-Text)